# I have a huge expression that I have evidence that it can be simplified but don't know how

Tags: summation

During work on my thesis, I am working on formulating a solution to some problem and I came across a huge and very complicated formula.

I tried plugging in a lot of different values and I have evidence that it can be simplified.

The formula is as follows:

$n$ is an integer bigger than one

$k$ is an integer which is smaller than $n$ and bigger than one.

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{r'=1}^{n}{ \sum_{c=0}^{i-1}\frac{{{r'-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r'}\choose{i-c-1}}}{{{n-1}\choose{i-1}}}\cdot\frac{  \sum_{r=n-k+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}}}$$
As I mentioned, I plugged in lots of different values for $n$ and $k$ and the expression always evaluated $k$.  Is it true that it always is equal to $k$?

Comment: What's your evidence that it can be simplified? In general it's a good idea to provide context to your question (such as where this expression came from and why you think it can be simplified).

Comment: @skyking Added a better explanation

Comment: @PeterTaylor Made a mistake, fixed now

Comment: You have $r'$s in a few places and $r$s in a few others; are those the same variable?

Comment: Did you try writing it down with factorials everywhere? Might not provide the full simplification you are looking for but it might as well induce somme cancelations that could help for the first steps.

Comment: Maybe I've got a bug in [my code](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/08868ded67d25a6a825467cd580124a7), but I'm not seeing many integers, let alone values equal to $k$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I made a mistake, c starts from 0 and not 1, fixed it and tried your code with that modification and it returns k just like in my experiments.

Comment: @RobinCarlier I did try but without success, maybe I'm just not smart enough haha

Comment: @StevenStadnicki They are not, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok, with that tweak it seems that $${\sum_{r'=1}^{n}{ \sum_{c=0}^{i-1}\frac{{{r'-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r'}\choose{i-c-1}}}{{{n-1}\choose{i-1}}}\cdot\frac{  \sum_{r=n-k+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}}} = k$$ for every $1 \le i \le n$, which simplifies things slightly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original goal

You want to show that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{r'=1}^n \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \frac{\binom{r'-1}{c} \binom{n-r'}{i-c-1}}{\binom{n-1}{i-1}} \frac{  \sum_{r=n-k+1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} }{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}\binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} } = k$$

But some empirical investigation suggests that a stronger statement is true, so my revised goal is

$$\sum_{r'=1}^n \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \binom{r'-1}{c} \binom{n-r'}{i-c-1} \frac{  \sum_{r=n-k+1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} }{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}\binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} } = k \binom{n-1}{i-1}$$

### Revised goal

If we start by reversing the order of the summations, we find that there's some symmetry which has been hidden:

$$\textrm{LHS} = \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \frac{ \left[ \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} \right] \left[ \sum_{r=n-k+1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} \right] }{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}\binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} } \\
= \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \frac{ \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} }{ \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}\binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} } \sum_{r=n-k+1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} \\$$

But when $r-1 < c$, we have $\binom{r-1}{c} = 0$, so the sum on top of the fraction in this new arrangement reduces to the sum on the bottom, and we have the much simpler

$$\textrm{LHS} = \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \sum_{r=n-k+1}^n \binom{r-1}{c} \binom{n-r}{i-c-1} \\$$

Now let's substitute $s = n-r$:

$$\textrm{LHS} = \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \sum_{s=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-s-1}{c} \binom{s}{i-c-1} \\$$

and it should be obvious that this can be identically equal to $k \binom{n-1}{i-1}$ iff $$s \ge 0 \implies \sum_{c=0}^{i-1} \binom{n-s-1}{c} \binom{s}{i-c-1} = \binom{n-1}{i-1}$$

But this is just a special case of Vandermonde's identity $$\sum_k \binom{r}{m+k} \binom{s}{n-k} = \binom{r+s}{m+n}$$

QED.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much 
I have a very similar formula for which I don't have a simplification. 
I don't know if this should be in a different question but here it goes:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{r'=1}^{n}{r' \cdot \sum_{c=1}^{i-1}\frac{{{r'-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r'}\choose{i-c-1}}}{{{n-1}\choose{i-1}}}\cdot\frac{ \sum_{r=n-k+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}{  \sum_{r=c+1}^{n}{{{r-1}\choose{c}}{{n-r}\choose{i-c-1}}{}}}}} $$

The only difference is the multiplication with $r'$.

Comment: Yes, that should be a separate question. I don't think the same techniques will necessarily work. It looks like when $n=k$ you get $n^2$, but otherwise the results are fractional.